# Locally stored images are not displayed in the CardView inside a RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have a `RecyclerView` which has `CardView` as its list items. The `CardView` have only 2 `TextView` and one `ImageView`.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:id="@+id/dcCardView">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/detail_coast_cardview_bg">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dcImage"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/radiation"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dcName"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="212"
            android:textSize="18dp" />

        <TextView
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:id="@+id/dcValue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="renu asdasasd"
            android:textSize="18dp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

The class that goes in it is this

```
public class DetailedCoastRecyclerView {

    //region fields
    private String name;
    private String value;
    private int imageName;
    //end region fields

    //constructor
    public DetailedCoastRecyclerView() {}

    public DetailedCoastRecyclerView(String name, String value, int image) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
        this.imageName = image;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public int getImageName() {
        return imageName;
    }
}
```

And my `CoastDetailsActivity2`

```
public class CoastDetailsActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Context context;
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    private int coastId;
    private String jsonCoastDetailsString = "";
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private DetailedCoastAdapter detailedCoastAdapter;
    private ImageView btnBlueFlag;
    private ImageView btnHandycapFriendly;
    private ImageView btnFavorite;
    private ImageView btnWaze;
    private LinearLayout mainLayout;
    private Beach mBeach;

    private TextView tvBeachName;

    private DetailedCoastWithForcast detailedCoastWithForcast;
    private DetailedBeachMetadata detailedBeachMetadata;
    private DetailedBeachHourlyForecast dbhfToday;
    private List<DetailedCoastRecyclerView> detailedCoastRecyclerViewList = new ArrayList<>();
    private Map<String, String> windBearing = new HashMap<>();
    private Map<String, String> jellyType = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_coast_details2);

        setPointer();
    }

    private void setPointer() {
        this.context = this;
        mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
        sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(sharedPreferencesName, MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        tvBeachName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBeachName);

        //start the forecast activity
        tvBeachName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, ForecastActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("coastId", coastId);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        AndroidNetworking.initialize(context);

        //get the coastId
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras == null) {
            //TODO add snackbar for error
        } else {
            coastId = extras.getInt("coastId");
        }

        getBeachDetails();

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.dcRecyclerView);
        detailedCoastAdapter = new DetailedCoastAdapter(detailedCoastRecyclerViewList, context);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(detailedCoastAdapter);
    }
}
```

And the adapter

```
public class ForecastAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ForecastAdapter.myViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    private List<DetailedCoastRecyclerView> dbhf0;

    public ForecastAdapter(Context context, List<DetailedCoastRecyclerView> dbhf0) {
        this.context = context;
        this.dbhf0 = dbhf0;
    }

    @Override
    public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.detailed_coast_card, parent, false);
        return new myViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(myViewHolder holder, int position) {
        DetailedCoastRecyclerView dcrv = dbhf0.get(position);
        holder.tvName.setText(dcrv.getName());
        holder.tvValue.setText(dcrv.getValue());
        //holder.ivImage.setImageResource(dcrv.getImageName());
        Glide.with(context).load(dcrv.getImageName()).into(holder.ivImage);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dbhf0.size();
    }

    public class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView ivImage;
        TextView tvName;
        TextView tvValue;

        public myViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ivImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dcImage);
            tvName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dcName);
            tvValue = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dcValue);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it, the `getBeachDetails()` method gets all the info from the server, add it to an `ArrayList` and calls `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter.

I know its working because I see the name and value for every card but the images which are stored locally are not displayed.

I use the same adapter inside a `ViewPager` with 3 fragments and there everything is ok.

Any ideas?

Comment: You are using DetailedCoastAdapter, however provided code of ForecastAdapter

Comment: What do you mean "use the same adapter inside a ViewPager with 3 fragments"? do you have recycler on one of your fragments? Do you use same DetailedCoast object and is dcrv.getImageName() a valid url/resource name?

Comment: didnt noticed that, in DetailedCoastAdapter the imageView was not defined. thanks man

Comment: you are welcome. You can accept my answer if it helped you and feel free to reassure any details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You provided code of ForecastAdapter, but actually you are using DetailedCoastAdapter. Make sure whether they are the same.
2. Check whether you have a valid url/resource in dcrv.getImageName()

Answer (score 0):

I guess your image resolution is too high that android buffer cant handle and throws exception while rendering your image, so as I know you have to decrease your image quality when loading it on `ImageView`.

In Picasso this is done like this by calling `resize(width,height)` method.

```
Picasso.with(context)
    .load(res)
    .resize(width,height)
    .placeholder(placeHolder)
    .into(view);
```

I guess it is done in the same way with Glide.